# Disable the Go button in the Keyboard for a UITextfield in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app has a screen where keyboard is always visible. The main element of the screen is a UITextfield. For easy data entering, keyboard is always made visible. When the user finishes entering data and hits Go, the app performs a 4,5 seconds action which is done in the background thread in order to show UIActivityIndicatorView.

My problem is that the Go button on the keyboard still shows as enabled since the logic is performed in the background. The user could potentially hit the Go again causing it to run again.

I am not able to set editable/userinteraction properties to No because then the keyboard disappears. Is there anyway just to disable the Go button or freeze the keyboard until the background thread returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly already have a UITextFieldDelegate set up to handle:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField;
```

Otherwise, you would not be able to perform accordingly already. Just return `NO` from that function if the background process is running and the keyboard should not close. Example:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
  if (alreadyPressedGo)
    return NO;
  ...
}
```

However, this will not "disable" the Go button, simply disable its functionality.

Comment: I thought about this. Would have been nice to give the user a feel that his action is being performed. He might get confused seeing the blue button and try to click again. Agreed that there is an activity indicator but it is easy to miss as it is nowhere near the keyboard.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just dismiss the keyboard once Go is pressed? You mentioned for ease of usage. Unfortunately, Apple enforces their human-computer interaction design upon all developers by making UIKeyboard closed...

Comment: Do you think they will reject the app if the keyboard is persisted?

Comment: I wouldn't really think so, but Apple does insist you follow their UI rules (submission guideline 10.1). I haven't combed through both Human Interface references, but I'm sure keyboard is in there somewhere, or at least text input.

Comment: ok,cool.. i don't necessarily agree with it but the requirement is to keep the keyboard visible always. I'll see what happens with that.

Comment: If I click the "clear button" while background thread is running, it sets the button to Grey. Anyway to manually invoke that event?

Comment: I give up and let the button do its thing ;)... but i'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Which "clear button" is this? If it's what I think it is (the [x] in the UITextField), I've never seen such behavior...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it (not at an OS X box at the moment otherwise I'd give it a go), but I'm wondering if you couldn't effectively disable it by placing a touch receiving UIImageView or similar on top of it. (You could even set the opacity of the UIImageView accordingly to achieve a greyed out look.)

This is combination with the disabling the operation of the button as @Skyler illustrated should be ideal.

Comment: This is also a good idea. I can position the grey button on top of the blue and show it only when needed though it is a stretch.

Comment: @coder net - Thought it would probably be less hassle to obscure the whole screen (with the UIActivityIndicatorView foremost) whilst the background task is processing.

Comment: Is there a way to do that easily?. I mean I just have the UIActivityIndicator control (not a separate view) right now which is located at some position in the view. It would have been nice if it had a setting that enabled a full screen view.